# Android Shell Command (or in adb) to automatically reboot and restore backup using cwm recovery

Tags: android, recovery, reboot

Looking for the command (or steps) to create a shell script on android that tells the device to reboot into recovery mode and automatically restore a backup located in the /sdcard/clockworkmod/backup/ folder. I know the reboot is:

```
reboot recovery
```

But I imagine there is something else I either need to add to that line or perhaps create a file somewhere that instructs cwm to automatically restore a backup and reboot.

Comment: You can check the CWM scripts in /system/bootmenu/script/

Comment: No such directory on the device. I also did a find -iname "bootmenu" and nothing. Would I need to have Rom Manager installed or just cwm recovery is good enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my own answer... For the folks in the ether...

1. Install ROM Manager Premium (small $$).
2. Use Koush's test rom manage project (https://github.com/koush/TestRomManager) to connect to ROM Manager and essentially ask it to reboot the device into recovery and do a backup. The system is actually incredibly powerful in that you can do some kool stuff over the air. This is a good setup for internally managed devices... You can even run your own update.zip scipts...
3. Optionally you can add a couple of exec lines to click ok automatically to the ROM Managers popup "do you want to reboot now?".

Thats it. Lots of research, as usual a Frankenstein of source from a great world full of devs.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the comments on this file, you will manage to do what you want
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bootable/recovery/+/fadc5ac81d6400ebdd041f7d4ea64021596d6b7d/recovery.c

Specifically, you will have to deal with the file

```
/cache/recovery/command
```

And include there the command you want to issue. Root access is needed to do so.

Alternatively, if your recovery admits it (CWM, TWRP) you can just use the `recovery` command through adb once you rebooted there.